# Check List to find out all values are same in R

Tags: r

I have list as follows

```
l = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"))
```

I want to check that each of them contain same values using apply family functions.

I want  following answer

```
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE
```

Comment: A bit unclear what the values of TRUE refer to. Is the value: "this item is the same as the others"? Or: "this item has at least one other match"? Or...? You might want to post more examples + expected results. What's the desired value for `list(1, 1, 1, 2)` or `list(1, 1, 2, 2)`, e.g.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `duplicated`

```
duplicated(l)|duplicated(l, fromLast=TRUE)
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

If we need to compare all the combinations of `list` elements, `combn` is another way

```
combn(seq_along(l), 2, FUN= function(x) all(l[[x[1]]] == l[[x[2]]]))
#[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: good answer, trying to figure out why `do.call(all.equal, l)` returns `TRUE` for `l = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "x"))`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  `all.equal` returns a single TRUE.  In this case, too, it seems to be comparing between all the elements, and returns a single TRUE.  You can change one of the list elements to say `l[[2]] <- "a"` and it says the `lengths differ`

Comment: @C8H10N4O2  Upon further investigation, it seems not to be the case. `l1 <- l; l1[[3]] <- 1;
do.call(all.equal, l1)
#[1] TRUE`  So possibly only the first two elements are compared?

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use the `apply` family, you  could do something like:

```
l = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"))
sapply(l, function(x) all.equal(x, l[[1]]))
# returns [1] TRUE TRUE TRUE
l = list(c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "c"), c("a", "b", "x"))
sapply(l, function(x) all.equal(x, l[[1]]))
# returns [1] "TRUE" "TRUE" "1 string mismatch"
```

Comment: @akrun's answer is better, this one just uses an `apply` function per OP